# How do i rewrite this url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like it to show the url
`/index.php?page=somePage&id=someID&siteAddress=someAddress`
as
`/someAddress/?page=somePage&id=someID`.

How can I use the rewrite rule for this?

Comment: Where is `someAddress` coming from? Is that the value of the `siteAddress` query string parameter?

Comment: Fixed to be clearer wording. siteAddress should be equal to someAddress, the value supplied between the two forward slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To internally rewrite */someAddress* to */index.php*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/$ /index.php?page=%1%id=%2&siteAddress=$1 [L]
```

To externally redirect */index.php* to */someAddress*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?page=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)&siteAddress=(^[&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%3/?page=%1&id=%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I would like to internally rewrite it, so I added that code to .htaccess. But the site did not display the resultant page. The site is http://public.forumzbb.com/test/?page=register&id=null. What I should be seeing on the page is is http://public.forumzbb.com/index.php?page=register&id=null&siteAddress=test. Yes, it should show up as a simple "Site Not Setup." text. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @user1748794 Are you placing these rules at the top of the htaccess file in your document root? Are you sure mod_rewrite is turned on? Do you have `AllowOverride All` set in your vhost/server config?

Comment: Oops, thank you. Solved now, just forgot to put 'RewriteEngine On' at the top of the file as well. Thank you again :)